# Android gradle build Error:(10, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I updated a plugin of Android studio. Now when I try to open an existing project I got an error.

```
Error:(10, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' 
Possible causes:The project 'TuteSample' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
```

This is my build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files    }
}allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Comment: is this gardle file of root folder or app folder?

Comment: Did you do a project rebuild? Clean project? Or invalidate caches? You could also try to open the project as a new project, it could work things out for you.

Comment: You have put the compile statement in the wrong file. It is the top level build file. It would be really good if you put this in the individual module build.gradle file as stated in the comment in the code you have added in the question.

Comment: compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+" remove this line.then Sync .....add this line to your project gradle file.

Comment: Thank you all I go the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure about it that your dependencies should be put into the individual module's build.gradle files instead of at the top most level build.gradle file. Placed your dependencies as:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
}
```

Add `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"` into  Module build.gradle would be:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your_package_name"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

        compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
       }
    }
   dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
    }
```

Top level build.gradle would be:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files    }
}allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Comment: My 'Module build.gradle' was missing there. How ever I copied build.gradle (Your second code) , pasted and saved. Then automatically 'Module build.gradle' was generated. Is that ok? Now it's working. Thank you very much for the support.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @Garima Mathur. I did that. Is that ok 'Module build.gradle' was generated automatically ? I think it's not affected to the project.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the  `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'` from project build.gradle into  module bulid.gradle . like this file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
}
```